# Unable to build Ad-Hoc iOS project from VS (Strip Assemblies Error)

Tags: xamarin.ios, osx-elcapitan

I get a error at build an adhoc IPA file for an IOS app in Visual Studio.

- iOS - "El Capitan"
- Xamarin for VS (3.11.1537)
- Xamarin.IOS 9.6.2.4
- XCode 7.0.1

The build-error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(654,3): error :
>   Could not strip assembly
>   /Users/Entwicklung/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/smensoSmartSalesTouch/3bff32d9a652aca79be94c7e13dfbf19/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Build/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.
>   5>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(654,3): error :
>   Could not strip assembly
>   /Users/Entwicklung/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/smensoSmartSalesTouch/3bff32d9a652aca79be94c7e13dfbf19/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Build/Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.dll.

I have find this ticket:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35786

and I have tryed this:
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks

My iOS-limits look like:

`cpu unlimited unlimited
filesize unlimited unlimited
data unlimited unlimited
stack 8388608 67104768
core 0 unlimited
rss unlimited unlimited
memlock unlimited unlimited
maxproc 2048 2048
maxfiles 262144 524288`

But the Problem remains. Have someone an Idea?

Thank you in advance and regards!